# c# idm using 'batch download from clipboard'(one of idm's functions)

Tags: c#

I want to make a program using C# (Windows Forms App) that if I click a button, assume that there are some addresses that I want to download in my clipboard already, then using 'batch download from clipboard' function, start downloading with IDM.

Anybody please help me to make it.

Batch download from clipboard

[image: batch download from clipboard]

Comment: Show what you've tried and where you are having a specific issue.

Comment: i found that I have to use the IDM API (http://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/support/idm_api.html) , and i have trouble with using it;  it 's COM based.

Comment: you can pass the file to download via command line. See a list of possible arguments [here](https://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/support/command_line.html).

Answer (score 0):

you should let operating system to decide which program to run. it will open a default browser and if the address has some file to download it will open your IDM.in "if" section, you can add some checking to see if the address ends with the extension you wanna download . The code-behind will be something like this

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           var  clipboard = Clipboard.GetText();
            if (clipboard.StartsWith("http://"))
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(clipboard);
            }
    }
```

Comment: actually i want to download with rtmp addresses(starts with rtmp://) and i don't want to let OS to change the default program to run. any other method possible?

Comment: downloading without opening browser is also easy but opening any idm ... i don't think it's possible.there is no standard call among all download managers to download a file.